# Duvida integração onPressed com Google Maps Flutter

Tags: android, ios, dart, flutter

Montei uma tela e estou com dificuldade de fazer uma coisa
Nos botões eu queria colocar pra funcionar o onPressed vinculado a API do google maps.
Tipo, qdo clicar em um dos botões, ele vai dizer quais são as lojas mais próximas, porém, como sou iniciante, estou tendo dificuldade pra fazer isso.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:fluttertoast/fluttertoast.dart';
```

void main() =>
    runApp(MaterialApp(debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false, home: GridLayout()));

class GridLayout extends StatelessWidget {
  List events = [
    "Clínica",
    "Petshop",
    "Farmácia",
    "Indefinido",
    "Hospital SOS",
    "?"
  ];

@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
            image: DecorationImage(
                image: AssetImage("assets/bg.png"), fit: BoxFit.cover)),
        child: Container(
            margin: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 10),
            child: GridView(
              physics: BouncingScrollPhysics(),
              gridDelegate:
                  SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(crossAxisCount: 2),
              children: events.map((title) {
                return GestureDetector(
                  child: Card(
                    shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(100.0),),
                    color: Colors.white60,
                    margin: const EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
                    child: FlatButton(
                        onPressed: (){

```
                    } ,
                    child: getCardByTitle(title)),
              ),
              onTap: () {
                Fluttertoast.showToast(
                    msg: title,
                    toastLength: Toast.LENGTH_SHORT,
                    gravity: ToastGravity.CENTER,
                    backgroundColor: Colors.blueAccent,
                    textColor: Colors.white,
                    fontSize: 16.0);
              },
            );
          }).toList(),
        )),
  ),
);
```

}

Column getCardByTitle(String title) {
    String img = "";
    if (title == "Clínica")
      img = "assets/clinic.png";
    else if (title == "Petshop")
      img = "assets/petshop.png";
    else if (title == "Farmácia")
      img = "assets/farm.png";
    else if (title == "Indefinido")
      img = "assets/img3.png";
    else if (title == "Hospital SOS")
      img = "assets/hosp.png";
    else
      img = "assets/expert.png";

`return Column(
  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
  children: <Widget>[
    Center(
      child: Container(
        child: Stack(
          children: <Widget>[
            Image.asset(
              img,
              width: 50.0,
              height: 50.0,
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    ),
    Text(
      title,
      style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20.0, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
      textAlign: TextAlign.center ,
    )
  ],
);`

}
}

[image: tter]

Comment: Não consegui compreender seu problema, mas olhando pelo print do celular eu teria uma solução... você já tentou usar o Widget [InkWell](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/InkWell-class.html)? você coloca seu Container dentro dele e o mesmo fica clicável.

Comment: Eu não sei se montei o código certo, mas visualmente é dessa forma que quero. O aplicativo é para encontrar lojas nas proximidades. Quando eu clicar por exemplo em "clínica", o app vai me mostrar quais as clínicas são mais próximas da minha localização, depois de selecionar uma, o app redireciona para o google maps. Acho que agora ficou mais claro

Comment: Pelo que entendi, a sua dúvida não é em relação a função `onPressed` em si e seu funcionamento, mas sim em como nessa função integrar com o Google Maps para mostrar os estabelecimentos por perto? Se esse for o caso, poderia atualizar o título para deixar mais claro

Comment: Alterei o titulo, e é exatamente essa a dúvida